# On developement mode everythink ok, but live web routes are not working

Tags: express, routes, web-hosting, host

I am very new on this world. I have a problem which is: when i am using visual studio localhost:3000 everything seems to be ok, but when i uploaded my files to hosting, express which is the package i am using for routes, is not working. I don't know what i am doing wrong.
I'll hope someone can help me i share my web and also github project.

https://alkosti.com/

https://github.com/JugoGastrico/altisk

**This is my app.js:** I used to have a 'Public' folder where I saved my css, images, scripts files, and inside this public folder I saved the others .html files keeping only outside the app.js file, where i have express and routes and my index.html. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgmCa.png) When I was developing and watching on localhost:3000 everything seems fine, the problem is when I uploaded to host. I could see only my index.html file without the styles applied live.
Then, I realized that the issue was on the root folder I was setting up. So what I did was changed it and all the css, .html files and scripts folders, I took it outside keeping the host files like these: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne09H.png).
And now is where I am stuck, I don't know where is the problem, because in Visual studio and local host everything is ok.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var path = require("path");
const port = 3000;
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});
app.get("/experiencia", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/experience.html"));
});
app.get("/contacto", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/contacto.html"));
});
app.get("/guess-the-number", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/guess-the-number.html"));
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I think here msut be the problem: in app.js file, which web is not reading that file.

Comment: where are you hosting? Have you for sure uploaded all the files?

Comment: Hi! Depperm :) I am hosting at hostinger. Yeah for sure all the files are uploaded, I really don't know if I need to do someting else or what is going on.

Comment: Provide some code samples or things you have tried. it will easy to understand it in that way.

Comment: Thankss for the comment! I really appreciate your help. I just uploaded more comments with images explaining what i tried to do and where i am stuck. I hope this can be more understanding.

Comment: based on your image you mention you put all the .html in the public folder, which I think means you need to move `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));` up above the rest or add public to the `sendFile` parameter value